# Django PayPal for the association of an automatic email sending

Tags: python, django, paypal-sandbox

Hi everyone I would like to know how you were able to manage once the customer clicks on the paypal payment button in your Django app, I would like to know how you were able to automatically manage sending an email in  his mailbox

indeed I can already manage the sending of emails automatically for a button button that I created myself but the case where I used the integration of paypal on the client side, I can't do it

Comment: @themadpdychologist Okay, Django PayPal for the association of an automatic email sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your server to take action when there is a payment, you should be using a server-side integration. Full stop.

Create two routes that return JSON, one for 'Create an Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).

Pair your two routes with the PayPal JS for approval: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

When an order is successfully captured by your server, have your server then immediately take the desired action (send the email). This is straightforward.